# CSS is not getting applied in eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse, primefaces

i'm new to primefaces and here is my question .i have configured the web.xml about my welcome page . however the stylesheet(css) is not getting linked(style.css) to the welcome page(login.xhtml) . i have used "" the path mentioned is also right .If i try to load that page alone (login.xhtml) , the webpage loads with styles applied . But when i choose to run my project by giving ( run -> run on server(Apache Tomcat v7.0.14) ) in eclipse, styles are not getting applied . can i know the reason ?

the error shown is "Apache Tomcat/7.0.14 - Error report"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you post the code for login.xhtml and style.css.

Comment: The error `Apache Tomcat/7.0.14 - Error report` is not related to your css not being applied. Please check your server.log file for any additional errors.

Comment: solved . need to give the path as css/style.css and not as ../css/style.css .